# Opening an modis hdf file in Envi and Calibration

Tags: envi, modis

I have downloaded an modis hdf file.it is l1 and its name is  MOD021KM ..I want to convert it to radiance.so I performed this steps in envi

Open>EOS>MODIS
selected modis hdf file.then I tried to run Radiometric Calibration but when I select the image it says image must have gain and offset for each band.I tried to opent image from open>generic format>hdf but there is not any hdf format there.

Anyway.I think envi does not recognize gains and offsets.I have checked metadata of opened file and the table of gains and offsets is empty.

I am using Envi 5.1

Can you please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Majid, you can use the 'read_sds_attributes' that comes with the MODAT tool suite to pick up this values. I think it is easier if you can script your process. Check here: http://scientiaplusconscientia.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/working-with-modis-l1b-from-scratch-3-calibration-conversion-to-radiance-at-top-of-atmosphere/

Comment: Slam.mn software installed, but I do not know envi mckt How do I install? Version 5.1 of our software is .... thanks

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use MCTK to convert MOD021KM data to radiance. MCTK is a plugin in ENVI and can also be used in IDL. This tool can be downloaded from [MCTK](https://github.com/dawhite/MCTK)

Comment: Thank you for your help.I tried to register to that site in case of downloading it but it has internal error..Is there any mirrors or sth like that to download?After converting to radiance Can I use it in ENVI?

Comment: I downloaded it but it is used to subset data..Where I can calculate radiance?

Comment: I am sorry. I made a mistake. Now I have revise it. You can use MCTK.